# I do not know how to create log trigger

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I need to create log trigger for after update, after insert and before delete.

In the accounts_history table I have more rows than in the table of accounts and it confuses me

How to write that trigger?

I tried to do it but I did not succeed, This is how I created tables and sequences.

I'm a beginner in Oracle and plsql

I'm sorry if I did not explain my problem well.

```
create table accounts (
  id number,
  name varchar2(32),
  amount number,
  date date
);

create sequnce acc_seq_id
  start wtih 1
  increment by 1
  nocache
  nocycle;

create table accounts_history (
  id          number
, old_name    varchar2(32)
, new_name    varchar2(32)
, old_amount  number
, new_amount  number
, change_date date
);
```

My trigger for only after update

```
create or replace trigger after_update
after update
on accounts referencing new as new old as old
for each row

begin

iNSERT INTO account_history
(
id, 
name,
old_name,
amount,
old_amount,
date
)
values
(
 :old.id,
 :new.name,
 :old.old_name,
 :new.amount,
 :old.old_amount,
 sysdate
);
end;
/
```

The error:

```
  SQL> show error
  Errors for TRIGGER AFTER_UPDATE:

  LINE/COL ERROR
  -------- --------------------------------------------------------------
   2/1   PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
   9/2   PL/SQL: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or
         column specification

   13/2  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.ID'
   14/2  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.NAME'
   15/2  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.OLD_NAME'
   16/2  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'NEW.AMOUNT'
   17/2  PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'OLD.OLD_AMOUNT'
   SQL>
```

Comment: Please contribute your trigger as well. With your given info I would assume, that every thing works fine. And more rows in the history table is absolutely normal why bother with it? Every change in base table leads to new row in history table, while in base table only existing row gets updated...

Comment: I posted my trigger for after update

Comment: The trigger looks absolutely fine to me. I don't know where your confusion comes from, but as i stated above your solution seems to be right. Perhaps you should enter some insert,update und delete statements and compare the data in the history table to better understand, what the data tells you: `SELECT * FROM account_history WHERE id = 42 ORDER BY date` would be a good start...

Comment: Perhaps one thing: i would write `nvl(:old.id, :new.id)` into the account_history table, as :old.id is null on insert. And use `after insert or update or delete`instead of `after update` only.

Comment: I posted my errors, If you can write me how it should look like my code

Comment: @perica - does your trigger's insert really refer to `date` instead of `change_date`? You've shown your `accounts` table with a column called `date`, which isn't allowed (unless you're using quoted identifiers, but don't do that). The table the trigger is on also doesn't have the `old_*` columns, so this is a bit confusing.

Comment: You need to do `SET DEFINE OFF` before creating a trigger with `:NEW` and `:OLD`, otherwise it'll treat them as bind variables.

Comment: @kfinity - no it won't; you're confusing bind and substitution variables I think, `set define` doesn't affect binds, and this is correct for triggers.

Comment: @perica - the bind errors suggest it isn't treating the whole thing as one statement. Are you maybe running this in SQL\*Plus? You may need to remove the blank line, or `set sqlblanklines on` - otherwise everything before the `begin` is being silently ignored.

Comment: can you correct my code and publish it?

Comment: @perica - you've also shown the secodn tabel being created as `accounts_history`, but your trigger inserts into `account_history`, without the `s`. But based on the other issues with column names and the typos in the sequence creation, it doesn't look like this is the code you are actually running, so that may be another discrepancy you introduced posting the question.

Comment: I corrected it in the code, but still get the error

Comment: @perica - with consisten names and APC;s changes, [it works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a8ecaff7bd36df2a4a94317a2ae1ac99). So, you need to figure out what you are doing differently.

Comment: I'll try to find error

Comment: I solved the problem, my fault on the table, THANK YOU VERY MUCH

Answer (score 2):

The values you insert come from the ACCOUNTS table, the columns you target come ACCOUNT_HISTORY table. You have mixed them up, which is why you get the ORA-01747 error. Try this:

```
create or replace trigger after_update
    after update on accounts 
    referencing new as new old as old    
   for each row
 begin
     INSERT INTO account_history
       (
    id, 
    new_name,
    old_name,
    new_amount,
    old_amount,
    change_date
)
values
(
     :old.id,
     :new.name,
     :old.name,
     :new.amount,
     :old.amount,
     sysdate
    );
End;
/
```

Comment: I removed blank lines

Comment: I solved the problem, my fault on the table, THANK YOU VERY MUCH